# minipage with verbatim package doesn't compile

Tags: verbatim, minipage

This is my code:

```
\usepackage{verbatim}
\newenvironment{listing}
{\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}\verbatim}
{\endverbatim\end{minipage}}
```

However, it doesn't compile:

```
Runaway argument?
! File ended while scanning use of \next.
<inserted text>
                \par
```

What is wrong?

Comment: You have also to use `\minipage` and `\endminipage` instead of `\begin{minipage}` and `\end{minipage}` respectlvely.

Comment: Problem solved?

Answer (score 10):

You have to do

```
\usepackage{verbatim}

\newenvironment{listing}
{\minipage{\linewidth}\verbatim}
{\endverbatim\endminipage}
```

There's almost the same example on page 3 of the package documentation, see the definition of the `fred` environment.

Note that `\begin{minipage}` executes (among other things) `\minipage` and similarly `\end{minipage}` executes `\endminipage`.